# Can I somehow modify a '&' array?

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

So basically I have this:

```rust
let mut sortedNumbers = numbers.clone();
    
sortedNumbers.sort_by(|a, b| b.rational.cmp(&a.rational));
```

Where `numbers` is a `&[..]`

I want to somehow sort the `sortedNumbers` vector, but the reference is not mutable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `numbers` is a `&[T]`, then `numbers.clone()` is also a `&[T]`, referring to the same array. What you want is `numbers.to_vec()` or `numbers.to_owned()`, which give you a `Vec<T>`, which you can then modify.

Comment: T in my case is a struct with two i32s. I'm trying to use to_vec() but it says that T type hasn't got the Clone trait implemented. How is this possible as long as I can do .clone() ?

Comment: Add `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` to your struct. When it wants to create a vector, it has to copy each element of the array to the new vector, and it tries to use `clone()` for that.

Comment: yes but I don't understand why let mut sortedNumbers = numbers.clone(); works then. Cuz like I'm using clone() without #defining(Clone) for the struct. Why does clone() work here?

Comment: Because it only clones the reference, not any elements.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense. Thanks Sebastian!